# Does charging a phone use the same power as a washing machine?

Tags: physics, mobile-phones

I heard that charging a phone is the same as running a washing machine in terms of electricity but from what I understand a typical phone charger uses ~5W whereas a washing machine is near ~500W.

Will charging my phone cost the same amount as running my washing machine?

Comment: Where did you hear this? You need to provide a link.

Comment: It is such nonsense (don't take this personal) that yes, some links are required to show that it is a notable claim.

Comment: No, it won't.  Not even close.  think about it, a washing machine has to heat a significant amount of water to 40 degrees for a typical load and maintain that temperature for the duration of the wash cycle, and that's not including the amount of energy needed to run the pumps and motors too.

Comment: @GordonM Washing machines don't heat water. The water heater heats water and keeps it hot. You can use cold water if you want.  However, it's not unreasonable to calculate hot water use into washing machine efficiency. As for me, I use cold water almost every time.

Comment: @fredsbend - In the UK most washing machines have a cold feed only, and heat the water themselves.

Comment: @AndyT Weird. The more you know.

Comment: @fredsbend Some washing machines can be plumbed into both the cold and hot water supply, but some will only take cold water.  Meanwhile some houses don't have a tap on the hot water feed in which case only cold water is available for the washing machine.  In either case all washing machines I've ever used had substantial water heaters incorporated in order to either heat the cold water or maintain the warm water at the correct temperature throughout the wash.

Comment: possibly you've confused this with EMF radiation, where a phone and washing machine are approximately the same

Answer (score 21):

This site calculates the use, in 2013, per year of your phone:

[How Much Electricity Do Your Gadgets Really Use?](https://www.forbes.com/sites/christopherhelman/2013/09/07/how-much-energy-does-your-iphone-and-other-devices-use-and-what-to-do-about-it/#1ea807532f70) (Forbes, 7 sep 2013)

It comes down to about 2kWh/year, assuming one full charge per day.

This site gives typical wattage for different appliances, and allows you to calculate annual usage based on hours/day and days/year the appliance is  used:

[Estimating Appliance and Home Electronic Energy Use](https://energy.gov/energysaver/estimating-appliance-and-home-electronic-energy-use) (energy.gov)

Assuming a washer is used 2 hours a day for 2 days a week, the total energy usage would be 53kWh.

So, according to these sources, its not even close